# E-Mail Header modification to avoid spam mail in Typo 3 (Power mail extension)

Tags: typo3-9.x

I created a form using power mail extension in typo3 and send the mail But the receiver got that mail-in the spam box. Please help to resolve this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this can not be resolved in general as it depends on the settings of the receivers mailbox.

1. you need to consider manual filters which detect special strings in body, header or sender of the email.
2. use clean mail headers (e.g. verify the mailserver as a server from the sender-domain)
3. there might be an automatic spam-detection which can be nearly anything (e.g. big mail provider like gmx.net or web.de consider one spam factor if a mail with the same content is delivered to hundreds of receivers).
   Here also special strings in the mail can add up for considering as spam.
   other usual spam factors: percentage of links in the mail, url of links.

Ask the mailserver admin.

If in doubt you need to be added to a whitelist of allowed sender domains.